# Googlebot and javascript

Tags: javascript, tracking, onchange, googlebot

My question is whether googlebot can track pages redirected through javascript onchange function:

Example:

```
<select id="bla">
    <option value="1">page1</option>
    <option value="2">page2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("bla").onchange = function() { // code to redirect }
</script>
```

Now, will googlebot be redirected to page2 or page1?

Comment: May be. See [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript) in Stack Exchange

Comment: As an aside, navigating onchange by `<select>` is horrible for usability and accessibility - and it means you can't use the keyboard to navigate because some browsers fire onchange events when using up/down on the select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation they "may not":

> "When Googlebot indexes a page containing JavaScript, it will index that page but it may not follow or index any links hidden in the JavaScript itself."

Check [this link](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355) for a little bit more insight in the subject.

Comment: This is obviously false. I just saw in my website's log how Googlebot indexed a url only accessible to Javascript.

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as a URL only accessible by javascript. You could hide it in javascript, but the URL is probably accessible by typing it in the address field in your browser as well. And there might as well be someone who have posted a direct link to your javascript hidden url from some other page, or just someone surfing around with a spoofed user agent. Or google might have changed their bot behavior since I posted the answare.